# How to read information from excel optimally without visiting every cell

Tags: python, excel, optimization

I have a problem. I want to read information from excel file, my first plan is to iterate through every cell and check if there is content in it if there is then read it otherwise move on.I think it is a very nonoptimal solution, can you suggest a better one?

Comment: have you looked into the pandas library? it has a `read_excel()` method that will handle this for you.

Comment: well, it depends on what you want from your script. Even if you use any external libraries, all of them will "iterate". If you use pandas library, you could remove/reduce empty cells and maybe reduce number of elements for iteration.